# Black screen when trying to create a menu

Tags: python, ubuntu, menu, window

I have a problem. I have made a menu for a game I am making with python (it is more of a start screen). However, when I run the code, I see a windows titled appropriately, but the screen itself is black. What am I doing wrong?

```
#importing the libraries
import pygame
import sys
import os

WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
#colour       R    G    B
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
RED       = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN = (  0, 155,   0)
DARKGREY  = ( 40,  40,  40)
BGCOLOR = BLACK

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

pygame.init()

#Drawing the message
def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render("Press a key to play...", True, DARKGREY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 200, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)



#Showing the start screen
def showStartScreen():
    titleFont = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)
    titleMain = titleFont.render('Badger Defense', True, WHITE, BGCOLOR)
    titleSecond = titleFont.render("Don't get your family killed!", True, GREEN)

while True:
    drawPressKeyMsg()


#Main function
def main():
    global DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT

    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 18)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Badger Defense - Aplha(0.0.1)')

    showStartScreen()



#Drawing the screen
DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
pygame.display.update()



#Reaction to the message
def checkForKeyPress():
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    os.system('python game.py')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am using Sublime and am running Ubuntu 12.04. I have the game and all its resources in the same folder as the menu, and I have a `__init__`.py file there as well.

Comment: First of all you need to indent your code so we will be able to read it, second you need to import os.

Comment: @Kobi K I have indented the code (cosmetic problem), but importing the os (`import os`) didn't solve anything. I still have the problem.

Comment: it wasn't suppose to solve it, it was just a quick bug i saw while skimming the code.

Comment: @Kobi K I solved the little bug. But could you propose how to solve the big one?

Comment: I'm not an expert on pygame but i think that your problem is that you are calling `pygame.display.set_mode` 2 times, you need to call it only once.

Comment: You never leave this loop, `while True:
drawPressKeyMsg()` what is in game.py

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham game.py is the actual game. It works perfectly. I can post the code if you like.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham http://pastebin.com/kCde2K3e

Answer (score 0):

Use [pygame.display.update()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html) to update the screen.

Comment: It is there, almost at the end.